# wcm io AemContextExtension mocking LanguageManager in JUnit 5

Tags: testing, junit, aem, junit5

I just upgraded our AEM codebase to use JUnit 5 but we are having some issues with some tests mocking specific methods of the LanguageManager.

```
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
@ExtendWith({AemContextExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
public class SomeComponentTest {

    @Mock
    private LanguageManager languageManager;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        ...
        context.registerService(LanguageManager.class, languageManager);
        ...
    }


    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        ...
        Page mockPage = mock(Page.class);
        given(languageManager.getLanguageRoot(any())).willReturn(mockPage);
        ...
    }
}
```

Even though I register the LanguageManager mock it still seem to get the WCM IO provided mock, which is initialized here: https://github.com/wcm-io/wcm-io-testing/blob/develop/aem-mock/core/src/main/java/io/wcm/testing/mock/aem/context/AemContextImpl.java ->     registerInjectActivateService(new MockLanguageManager());

Am I doing something wrong here or is there just no way to spy / mock the methods of the LanguageManager. Do note that in the past this worked when using:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer over here: https://wcm-io.atlassian.net/browse/WTES-58?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=21269#comment-21269

```
context.registerService(LanguageManager.class, myCustomLanguageManager,
Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, 100);
```

Or

```
this.mockLanguageManager = context.registerService(LanguageManager.class, 
spy((MockLanguageManager)context.getService(LanguageManager.class)), 
Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

// Now you can leverage the mocked language manager that is provided, while 
you can still override some of the methods if desired, due to it being a spy
```